# Merging an ordinal variable into categories based on the mean value of unknown groups

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, clustering, categorical-data, ordinal-data

I have a dataset  consisting of subjects with a number of measurements associated with each them. Each of a subjects measurements has a time series associated with it and all patients have the same set of measurements.

I have been told that the nominal value of the measurements can be grouped into categories (I am expecting two to four groups per measurement) based on another discrete ordinal variable $a \in A | \forall a \in \mathbb{Z} \land a \ge a_{min} \land a \le a_{max}$.

I would like to create categories of similar groups for each measurement (i.e. the categories can be different for different measurements) based on the following constraints:

- Within a group of subjects, the means for a given measurement of the associated time series should be statistically similar between the subjects within the group.
- Between groups the means of the time series for a given measurement should be statistically different.
- Categories should retain the ordinal relationship that was there before i.e. category 1 might contain values 1,2 and 3, while category 2 might contain 4 and 5 etc., however, category 1 with values 1 and 3, and category 2 with values 2, 4 and 5 should not be allowed.
- The minimum number of groups based on the 3 constraints given above.

Does anyone know if there there a specific method to do this? I wondered about using clustering , however I don't know a method of doing this while maintaining the ordinal nature of the data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!